# Date format with Timestamp and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, date

I have an entity with a Timestamp field corresponding to a DATE column in the Oracle database.

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    private Tiemstamp purchaseDate;
    //more fields...
}
```

When I insert a row, DATE format in the database is "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", but I want it to be just "dd/MM/yyyy".

How can I define the format?

Comment: Date data types in a database do not have a format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ignore `time` in a `Date` attribute in `Java` and `Hibernate`, declare your attribute as `java.util.Date` and either use the annotation `@Type(type="date")` along with it or use the `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` annotation with it.

Here's what you need:

```
@Column
@Type(type="date")
private Date purchaseDate;


@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date purchaseDate;
```

Because `Timestamp` is designed to hold both `date` and `time`, whereas `Date` holds only the `date`.

Please refer to [**HIBERNATE DATE VS TIMESTAMP** Article](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2012/02/hibernate-date-vs-timestamp/) for further details.

Comment: I've tried with both and it is still storing the time. This is in server side. From client, I send a timestamp and, in the server, I build the date from that timestamp, call order.setPurchaseDate(theDate) and persist the entity.

Comment: Yes but I forgot to mention that you should change it from `TIMESTAMP`to `DATE` in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the Oracle data type is called Date, it always stores datetime.
The Oracle database does not have a data type that is unique to date without the time.
In Java, instead of using the Timestamp use java.sql.Date.
Do not worry about it, the Hibernete makes this treatment a safe and transparent manner.

Comment: And here I thought their non-standard implementation of arrays was the second-weirdest thing in that database. Then again, it's the only thing I've tried out. This moves it down to third.